# Linker error undefined reference even if functions are defined in shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, linker-errors

I´m trying to modify a piece of C++ code (developed under Linux with gcc toolchain) using in it new functions that are defined in two libraries, one shared library (called libsio4_api.so) and a static library (called sio4_main.a). The original code is built with a makefile that first creates a shared library linking toghether various object files and then links this library with the main object file.
This is the line that links the shared library:

```
g++ -s -shared main.o RTLinkResolution.o IORefresh.o UserProgramImpl.o UserProgramDataManager.o UserProgramCode.o -L./genericFiles/lib -lUserProgramEnvironment -lm -o libUProg.so
```

I modified it in this way to add to the linkage my libraries (-pthread is needed by one of them):

```
g++ -s -shared -pthread libsio4_api.so sio4_main.a main.o RTLinkResolution.o IORefresh.o UserProgramImpl.o UserProgramDataManager.o UserProgramCode.o -L./genericFiles/lib -lUserProgramEnvironment -lm -o libUProg.so
```

This linking terminate without errors and in the resulting lib I can see the functions I want to use (in this example I show just one but also the others are present):

```
nm -D libUProg.so | grep sio4_async_init
000000000006d581 T sio4_async_init
000000000006dcae T sio4_async_init_data
             U _Z15sio4_async_initv
```

The problem is that when the final linking is done the functions are not found:

```
g++ -o test main.o libUProg.so -pthread sio4_main.a libsio4_api.so
libUProg.so: undefined reference to `sio4_async_close(int)'
libUProg.so: undefined reference to `sio4_async_init()'
libUProg.so: undefined reference to `sio4_async_open(int, int, int*)'
```

I searched already for similar problems in other topics and I found out that the order in which libraries are fed to the linker is important, but even if I change the order in the final linking command those functions are not found.
Does someone have any clue about how I can proceed?

Comment: Did you forgot to `extern "C"`? Does `libUProg.so` come from a C source file?

Comment: That´s maybe the problem. The new libraries are compiled with gcc from source files written in C, while here I´m compiling a c++ code with g++.

Comment: Then research what is name mangling and what does `extern "C"` do.